# css accordion jumping to top of screen

Tags: html, css, accordion

I am using an accordion that is purely css. The panels have a anchor which has the # link, example: `<a href="#whatever">`.

When a panel is selected that particular panel jumps to the top of the screen & I am assuming this is because of the # in the link. Is there a way I can disable this so that the accordion panel doesn't jump at all but stays where it is on the screen and it animates the panel opening at that point?

What I find weird is when I built the accordion on it its own it works fine, no jumping. When I insert the code (both HTML & CSS) into my webpage it then jumps on selection/click. I am not sure why, I have copied the code like for like.

My experience doesn't go beyond HTML & CSS at the moment.

**UPDATE**
I have now deduced that there is something with my footer causing this. I decided to add (just the HTML) piece by piece of my webpage into the file where the accordion works as should. Header added with no issue but once I add the HTML for the footer, the accordion starts the jumping.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code, please? Thanks.

Comment: it is up pn jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/minternetmike/qoq43xq6/

Comment: You should put that code in the question, not just link to it in a comment, so that others can easily find it and see what you're asking about.

Comment: your css is making use of the :target pseudo selector, this will always position the cursor on the item that you clicked in the accordion. I don't know that there is a pure css fix for this, have a look here: http://css-tricks.com/on-target/ (Jumping beahviour). If you were using a js/jquery accordion it would be very easy to fix.

Comment: Here is one that doesn't jump, but of course your markup will have to be very different. http://jsfiddle.net/Wolfy87/Z4Mr3/

Comment: thanks lharby, I will check out css-tricks. I have another accordion as a back-up but I like this one because of the effect with the title/heading of the panel + it's annoying me as to why it jumps when on my webpage but not if it is on it's own. Me being me can't let it go and need to find out why - that's how we learn :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.faq-accordion:hover {
position:absolute;
top:200px;
left:50%;
margin-left:-480px;
padding:20px;
background-color:rgba(79,79,79,1);
border:6px solid rgba(60,159,138,1);
}
```

Comment: thanks Rounin, I tried that and when you hover over the accordion it appears to come out of the page, like a modal/lightbox effect, however the panels no longer jump.
I have now found there seems to be a conflict with the footers html that causes the accordion to jump.

Comment: Yep, giving the accordion `position:absolute;` in a `:hover` state, was the only way I could get it to stop jumping about the page. I've given the hovered-over accordion a `border:` - and to enhance it further, you could even add a drop-shadow.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't particularly like that. I prefer to keep the accordion within the page. It's baffling me why it is jumping when it doesn't do that when I built it from the tut. + as I have added to my above comment and the initial post, it appears the issue in is the footers html